# Is there away to compile node.js in eclipse + mingw on windows?

Tags: windows, node.js, compilation, eclipse-cdt

im new to node.js . currently i develop all my stuff ( c++/web/java ) on one IDE eclipse 
i want to start to develop with node.js . from looking on the web i didn't found any strict answer
but can i compile node.js in eclipse cdt on windows ?
Thanks

Comment: Node.js is available on Windows. Why would you want to compile it yourself?

Comment: learn and modify it for my needs

Comment: I cannot see any reasons why you couldn't. You would have to create your own project and make sure all the dependencies are satisfied. I suspect you cannot find an answer because this isn't something that people would commonly do, it would be extremely rare due to it being available under windows. 
That said, if you wish to use specific modules, like serial port or bcrypt, then your going to have issues on 64-bit windows. But that's generic for windows, not specific to eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to build/compile Node.js on Windows following [this guide](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation#building-on-windows).

However, as it has been already mentioned here, Node.js is already available on Windows. You can just [install it](http://nodejs.org/download/#installers).

Installing it would most likely be the least painful way to go.